# Laravel: Check checkbox if true or false, then update database

Tags: php, laravel

Just started with laravel using phpStorm. Im trying to create a form that take inputs, and a checkbox, then adds it to a database.
All of the rows in the database get listed in the view index.html. The user should be allowed to activate or deactivate (with the checkbox) the the message that should be listed when browsing the index.html file. Because if a news article is active, and you want to deactivate it, you should be able to just uncheck the checkbox, and it will be deactivated.
So I am wondering how my function should look like.

Im also unsure how to run the function ActivatedOrDeactivated when the checkbox gets checked or unchecked.

Its my first post, so please tell if something is hard to understand in my description.

My route:

```
Route::get('admin',
    [
        'uses' => 'NyhetsController@index',
        'as' => 'admin.index'
    ]
);


Route::get('admin/create',
    [
        'uses' => 'NyhetsController@create',
        'as' => 'admin.create'
    ]
);

Route::post('admin',
    [
        'uses' => 'NyhetsController@store',
        'as' => 'admin.store'
    ]
);

Route::get('admin/{id}',
    [
        'uses' => 'NyhetsController@show',
        'as' => 'admin.show'
    ]
);

Route::get('admin/{id}/edit',
    [
        'uses' => 'NyhetsController@edit',
        'as' => 'admin.edit'
    ]
);

Route::put('admin/{id}',
    [
        'uses' => 'NyhetsController@update',
        'as' => 'admin.update'
    ]
);

Route::get('admin/{id}/delete',
    [
        'uses' => 'NyhetsController@delete',
        'as' => 'admin.delete'
    ]
);

Route::delete('admin/{id}',
    [
        'uses' => 'NyhetsController@destroy',
        'as' => 'admin.destroy'
    ]
);
```

My Controller that contains the function (just something i wrote in anger):

```
public function ActivatedOrDeactivated($id){
$news = News::findOrFail($id);
$input = Input::get('active');

if($input == true)
{
    $news->active = 'false';
    $news->update($input);
}
else{
    $news->active = 'true';
    $news->update($input);
}
}
```

My index file that contains the form:

```
<h1>Alle postene i databasen</h1>

<p>{{ link_to_route('admin.create', 'Legg til ny nyhet') }}</p>


@if($news->count())
    <table class="table table-striped table-boarded">
        <thead>
            <tr>ID</tr>
            <tr>Title</tr>
            <tr>Author</tr>
            <tr>Message</tr>
            <tr>Active</tr>
            <tr>Picture path</tr>
            <tr>Activate/Deactivate</tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            @foreach($news as $n)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $n->id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $n->title }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $n->author }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $n->message }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $n->active }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $n->picture_path }}</td>
                    <td>{{ Form::checkbox('active') }}</td>
                    <td>{{ link_to_route('admin.destroy', 'Delete', array($n->id)) }}</td>

                </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: A checkbox doesn't get posted when it is not checked (it isn't in the $_POST array). You can solve this by giving active a default value.    Input::get('active', false);

Comment: No, since i do not quite understand how to run the function when the checkbox gets checked or unchecked

Comment: Do you want to save the row when a user checks the checkbox in the table? You don't have form tags around the checkbox, so I presume you want to do it with javascript/jquery?

Comment: Im quite new to this all, so at first im trying to do it all without javascript and jquery. I just want to update the value in the database if the user check or uncheck the checkbox. So that i later can show only activated news in another view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to update the news item when a user clicks the checkbox without ajax this would a way to do it:

router.php

```
Route::post('admin/{id}/active',
    [
        'uses' => 'NyhetsController@toggleActive',
        'as' => 'admin.toggle_active'
    ]
);
```

HTML index.blade.php

```
@if($news->count())
    <table class="table table-striped table-boarded">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Author</th>
                <th>Message</th>
                <th>Picture path</th>
                <th>Active</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            @foreach($news as $n)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $n->id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $n->title }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $n->author }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $n->picture_path }}</td>                        
                    <td>{{ $n->message }}</td>
                    <td>
                        {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'admin/' . $n->id . '/active')) }}
                        {{ Form::submit('', [ 'class' => ($n->active ? 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok' : 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove') ]);
                        {{ Form::close() }}
                    <td>{{ link_to_route('admin.destroy', 'Delete', array($n->id)) }}</td>

                </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
@endif
```

NyhetsController

```
public function toggleActive($id) {
    $news = News::findOrFail($id);
    if($news->active)
    {
        $news->active = 'false';
        $news->update($input);
    }
    else{
        $news->active = 'true';
        $news->update($input);
    }
}

return Redirect::to('admin');
```

Code is untested!

Comment: I would also suggest by not providing a link to delete a news item, but using REST methods. You have to wrap the delete in a form so you can post it with the DELETE http method.         http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-beginners-guide-to-http-and-rest--net-16340

Comment: It worked, just had to tweek it a bit!
Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

In your Form::

```
{{ Form::checkbox('active', 'true') }}
```

In your Controller

```
$news = News::findOrFail($id);

if (Input::get('active') === 'true') {
    $news->active = 'true';  // UPDATE:must be true of course
    $news->update($input);
} else {
    $news->active = 'false'; // UPDATE:must be false of course
    $news->update($input);
}
```

By the way: you could save yourself some typing if you simply [route restfully](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#restful-resource-controllers) using

```
Route::resource('admin', 'NyhetsController');
```

Comment: It actually works for the most part. If the row that is shown in the index is active (true), and you click the checkbox, the value updates to inactive (false) in the database. But when i try to activate a inactive post, nothing happens. No error aswell. So it means the logic is not correct in the Controller?

Comment: well, i think i swapped it :/. ill update the answer. stupid typo... sry 'bout that.. was false in the question in the first place btw ;)